# What does the ? mean in this case?

Tags: typescript, syntax

I have a debat with my college about the signification of the ? in this case:

```
<h1>{{userVisited?.firstName}} {{userVisited?.lastName}}</h1>


export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  userVisited : User;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.foo.subscribe(res => this.userVisited = res.user);
  }
}
```

So before the loading, userVisited is undefined. That's why there is the undefined error.

That means an optional variable or it's to avoid "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined" if the variable is not loaded yet?

Or anything else?

Comment: This doesn't look like vanilla javascript

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, I updated my question

Comment: That looks like *some unspecified* template language. You'll need to tell us what it is.

Comment: @Tushar yes, it's a duplication!